# XLA JIT optimization on CPU

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-xla

I am trying to take a saved model (or  frozen graph) and enable XLA JIT compilation.
I use the configProto Optimization options to set it to L1 , but it doesnt seem to make any difference to execution of the TF graph.
I read that it has to be done manual mode and not just at session level. Are there any examples or can you point me to some code pointers , where I can run xla Jit compilation taking an already saved model architecture (saved model bundle or frozen graph).

Comment: Can you share any code that you are using? For instance, how are you loading the frozen graph? Where are you applying the session config options?

Comment: @Tyler : i just create configProto with jit optimization on and create session using that config and do session run in my java/c++ code .